# Handle navigation to alert unsaved changes

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-navigation-stack

I'm using defaultGetStateForAction from react-navigation to intercept my navigation so i can alert my user that there are unsaved data, and give him option to continue navigation and delete unsaved data or save it first. This data is stored into a higher component state which can be accessed by a function available via screenProps

So... here's my code:

```
const CreateAnimalStack = createStackNavigator({
    CreateAnimal: { screen: createAnimalScreen },
    ListAnimals: { screen: listAnimalsScreen },
    DetailAnimal: { screen: detailAnimalScreen },
    ReviewAnimal: { screen: reviewAnimalScreen },
    ListMarks: { screen: listMarksScreen },
    CreateMark: { screen: createMarkScreen },
}, {
        initialRouteName: 'CreateAnimal',
    });

const defaultGetStateForAction = CreateAnimalStack.router.getStateForAction;

CreateAnimalStack.router.getStateForAction = (action, state) => {
    if (
        state &&
        action.type === NavigationActions.BACK &&
        state.routeName === 'CreateAnimal' &&
        state.routes[state.index].routeName === 'ReviewAnimal' &&
        state.index === 1
    ) {
        Alert.alert(
            'Alert Title',
            'My Alert Msg',
            [
                { text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed') },
                {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    onPress: () => {
                        return null;
                    },
                    style: 'cancel',
                },
                {
                    text: 'OK', onPress: () => {
                        const routes = [
                            { routeName: 'CreateAnimal' },
                        ];
                        return {
                            ...state,
                            routes,
                            index: 0,
                        };
                    }
                },
            ],
            { cancelable: false },
        );
        return state;

    } 
    return defaultGetStateForAction(action, state);
};

export default CreateAnimalStack;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem here is that `Alert` is not blocking so the navigation would still happens behind the Alert.

That being said, from the [react-navigation documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/routers.html#blocking-navigation-actions) you should return `null` inside of the `if` statement : it will cancel the navigation.

```
if (...) {
  Alert.alert(
      'Alert Title',
      'My Alert Msg',
      // ...
  );

  return null;
}
```

Then in Alert OK button resolution, you have to re-dispatch a navigation action (instead of returning the state), but the problem then is you don't have `dispatch` available. `dispatch` is coming from `AppContainer`. One approach is to create a `NavigationService` which store the navigator, like [described in the doc](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html#docsNav), and export it from `dispatch`.

```
// ...
{
    text: 'OK', onPress: () => {
        const action = NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'CreateAnimal', params: {}});

        // here you have to call dispatch from the AppContainer navigator (NavigationService ?)
        NavigationService.dispatch(action);
    }
},
```

All this code seems to me fragile and very ugly.

I'm suggesting you should first explore a total different way, for example by replacing the default `headerLeft` component with screen `navigationOptions` with a custom onPress callback, instead of listening for state changes.

Here is a simple, non-tested example which import the default left button from react-navigation.

```
import { HeaderBackButton } from 'react-navigation';

class YourScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const onBack = {
      Alert.alert(
        'Alert Title',
        'My Alert Msg',
        [
            { text: 'Ask me later', onPress: () => console.log('Ask me later pressed') },
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                style: 'cancel',
            },
            {
                text: 'OK', onPress: () => {
                    navigation.goBack();
                }
            },
        ],
        { cancelable: false }
      );
    }

    return {
      headerLeft: <HeaderBackButton  onPress={() => onBack()} />
    }
}
```